# C- pattern matching

Tags: c, pattern-matching

I am trying to write a program that receives input infinitely and whenever an input sequence matches a given pattern it should print that a match has been found and continue searching for other occurrences of the pattern I managed just to code this

```
   #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>
    int main(){
      char ch;
      char pattern[4]="1234";
      int i=0;
      while(1){
        scanf(" %c",&ch);
        if(ch==pattern[i]){
          i+=1;
        } else {
            i = 0;
        }
        if (i == 4) {
            printf("match found!\n");
            i = 0;
        }
        //printf("%c",ch);
      }
      return 0;
    }
```

The problem is that this code doesn't handle repetion cases like 11234 .

my other approach uses buffering, that has some error

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(){
  char ch;
  char pattern[4]="1234";
  char buf[4] = "";
  int i=0;
  while(1){
    scanf(" %c",&ch);
    buf[i%4]=ch;
    i++;
    if(strcmp(pattern,buf)==0){
      printf("Match found");
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Help me fix the problem

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm

Comment: [Exact string matching algorithms](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~lecroq/string/index.html) is pretty useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when a given character, let's say the second `1` entered, does not fulfill the `if(ch==pattern[i])`-condition, you "reset" the pattern but you will not check this already entered `1` for the beginning of the "new" pattern check. So write the following:

```
else {
   i = (ch==pattern[0]) ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: This can run into a problem if the pattern to be found is `1213` and the input is `121213`.  There's clearly a match, but when the second 2 fails to match 3, resetting back to the beginning of the pattern means that the 1213 is missed.